# Magento 2 : List all api user and role belong to a particular user

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

In magento 1 I did the below code, which worked fine.

Step 1: Fetch all the active api user list
    try{
            require_once '../app/Mage.php'; 
            Mage::app();

```
        $usermodel = Mage::getModel('api/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $id = $usermodel->getColumnValues('user_id');$name = $usermodel->getColumnValues('username');
        $api_key = $usermodel->getColumnValues('api_key');
        echo '<pre>';print_r($api_key);exit;

        $ulist = array_combine($id,$name);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


$rolemodel = Mage::getModel('api/role')->getCollection();
$role_id = $rolemodel->getColumnValues('role_id');
$role_name = $rolemodel->getColumnValues('role_name');
$list = array_combine($role_id,$role_name);
```

Step 2: $_GET['id'] = $apiUserId;
Fetch role that belong to a given api user id.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $usermodel = Mage::getModel('api/user')->getCollection();
    $id = $usermodel->getColumnValues('user_id');$name = $usermodel->getColumnValues('username');
    $ulist = array_combine($id,$name);


    $role_id_under_selected_user = Mage::getModel('api/user')->loadByUsername($ulist[$_GET['id']])->getRoles();
    $role_id_under_selected_user = $role_id_under_selected_user[0];
    $rlist = array();
    if($role_id_under_selected_user)
    $rlist[$role_id_under_selected_user] = $list[$role_id_under_selected_user];     
}
```

I need to do the same in magento 2. Can anyone help?

Comment: first.Mage:: deprecated at magent 2.magento 1 code  is not working on magento 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your magento root create **UserRole.php**

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    include('app/bootstrap.php');
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $roleAuthModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Authorization\Model\Role');
    $userModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\User\Model\User');


    //list all apiuser
    $usermodel = $userModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $id = $usermodel->getColumnValues('user_id');
    $name = $usermodel->getColumnValues('username');
    $userList = array_combine($id,$name);//all api user


    //list all role
    $rolemodel = $roleAuthModel->getCollection();
    $role_id = $rolemodel->getColumnValues('role_id');
    $role_name = $rolemodel->getColumnValues('role_name'); 
    $roleList = array_combine($role_id,$role_name);// all role

    //role_id against user_id

     $user_id = 11;//suppose user_id =11
    $role_id_under_selected_user = $userModel->loadByUsername($userList[$user_id])->getRoles();
```

You get the role_id against username.